# My first time vs. the first time I had

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

> This was my first time seeing a teacher cry.
>
> This was the first time I'd seen a teacher cry.

Question 1: Is there any difference between the two?

Question 2: Which is more common/sounds more natural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are Correct , both are Common , both are Natural !

Here is a slight subtle Difference , which may or may not be intentional :

> My team of Academic Evaluators had seen a lot & **most of them** had seen teachers cry, but ....
> This was **my** first time seeing a teacher cry.

> I had **heard** of teachers crying when Academic Evaluators ask tough questions, but ....
> This was the first time I'd **seen** a teacher cry.

Point is not to worry too much about the "better" or "best" way , in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of syntax, I think it is more common to use relative clauses (as in "first time **that I'd seen a teacher cry**") in spoken English than written. In written English, however, non-finite verb phrases (a participle phrase in this case, as in "first time **seeing a teacher cry**") may be preferred to a relative clause for its conciseness(reduced word count and fewer finite verbs).